# yii2 attribute display a value in a view

Tags: yii2

I have an attribute house_id,  I want to get the address from the house_id and display it in a view.

My view

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        'house_id',
    ],
]) ?>
```

Thanks

Edit:
Here is the solution  Thanks to Raditz for the help.
Model:

```
public static function getHouseAddressPayroll($house_id)
{
    if ($house_id) { $house = House::findOne($house_id);
        $address = $house->address_line_1.', '.$house->city.', '.$house->state.' '.$house->zipcode;
        return $address;
    } else {
       $data = "N/A";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        [
        'attribute' => 'first_house',
            'value' =>  House::getHouseAddressPayroll($model->first_house)
        ],
        [
        'attribute' => 'second_house',
            'value' =>  House::getHouseAddressPayroll($model->second_house)
        ],
        [
        'attribute' => 'third_house',
            'value' =>  House::getHouseAddressPayroll($model->third_house)
        ],
        [
        'attribute' => 'fourth_house',
            'value' =>  House::getHouseAddressPayroll($model->fourth_house)
        ],

    ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very generic. It would be more helpful if you share more info. But I will take a  guess at what you trying to achieve.

I assume the address is stored in another table called "house" with a model House. Assuming your current model is called Profile. In Profile model, you would need to have a 1-to-1 or 1-to-many relation function with the House model.

Assuming the relation is 1-to-1. Your relation function would looks something like below:

```
public function getHouse()
{
    return $this->hasOne(House::className(), ['id' => 'house_id']);
}
```

Now that you have set the relation for both table, in your DetailView widget, you could do something like this:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
      'id',
      'house.address'
    ]
]) ?>
```

address is the column name in your house table. If you have more than 1 columns that you want to use, you could use a function like below:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
       'id',
       [                     
         'attribute' => 'house_id',
         'value' => function ($model, $widget){
            return $model->house->address1.'<br/>'.$model->house->address2;
         }
       ],
    ]
]) ?>
```